# Unity Raycast Ignores LayerMask

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, layer

for some reason my raycast hits objects, that are in another layer.

```
private int obstaclesLayerMask = (1 << 11) | (1 << 12);
private Vector3 GetPointOfContactNormal()
{
    Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out hit, obstaclesLayerMask))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
        return hit.normal;
    }

    return Vector3.zero;
}
```

I`ve tried changing layerMask to random layers even the ones not specified like 1 << 30 and tried to use LayerMask.GetMask() instead, but raycast still hits objects. Only setting layerMask to default layer like 1 << 0 made raycast ignore collisions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also to add to the above mentioned answer, i found something else that from my knowledge wouldn't work.

It seems like you are placing the `obstaclesLayerMask` in the distance Parameter of the `Physics.Raycast`

these are all the Parameters:

1. origin:  The starting point of the ray in world coordinates.
2. direction:   The direction of the ray.
3. maxDistance: The max distance the ray should check for collisions.
4. layerMask:   A Layer mask that is used to selectively ignore Colliders when casting a ray.
5. queryTriggerInteraction: Specifies whether this query should hit Triggers.

the argument range would be correct if you change it to this:

```
//I put it on 300f here but just put there what you prefer.
if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out hit, 300f, obstaclesLayerMask))
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem, I got confused, because in Linecast you don`t have to put distance parameter before the mask, but here you do.

Comment: Nice, my first answered question on here haha, it is also in the unity API at: [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)